Why following error occurred when try to install Angular CLI globally
Following error occurred when trying to install:
npm install -g @angular/cli

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/a28abb5a
npm ERR! dest /Users/user/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/49/6a/4875bf54e614bb063b54bc15d4e14abeb661019ad0d79239ca8d72381b4912fc3be9b884e96ecc36cecd20c048d0cee9af66aa3cfbbc1f39504ed51fc3e7
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/ip-address: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/a28abb5a' -> '/Users/user/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/49/6a/4875bf54e614bb063b54bc15d4e14abeb661019ad0d79239ca8d72381b4912fc3be9b884e96ecc36cecd20c048d0cee9af66aa3cfbbc1f39504ed51fc3e7'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/user/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/49/6a/4875bf54e614bb063b54bc15d4e14abeb661019ad0d79239ca8d72381b4912fc3be9b884e96ecc36cecd20c048d0cee9af66aa3cfbbc1f39504ed51fc3e7
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2024-09-12T01_45_41_421Z-debug-0.log

What is the issue with npm? How to resolve this error?

The message say

EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/a28abb5a'

So, it seems a write operation issue with your file that already exist.
Check for npm processes running and shutdown,
you can try clearing your cache data with

npm cache clean --force

Then, run again your command

npm install -g @angular/cli

If the error continues, check for filesystem permissions.

Can't it happen due to a variable path issue?
